# Inconsistent rendering in Explorer and Firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, rendering

The following code renders differently in Firefox and Internet Explorer. Is there any good reasons for it?

The attempt here is to have some equally sized coloured boxes with styled links inside them. Presently the text links are working as they should with Firefox, but Explorer decides that they should be outside the textbox. The reason for the surrounding box is that they alter colour on hover, making the hyperlinks more visible.

Thank you for comments.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML Basic 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-basic/xhtml-basic11.dtd">
<html  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8'/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/> 
<style>
.menu {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin-top:20pt
    }
.menubuttons {
    left:0%;
    height:100%;
    padding-top:20%;
    display:inline;
    position:static;
    top:20pt;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 0 0 20pt;
    }
#menubutton {
    border-radius:16px;
    background:lightblue;
    color: #000066;
    position:relative;
    height:15%;
    display:inline;
    width:60pt;
    padding:10pt 5pt 10pt 5pt;
    margin:3pt 0 3pt 3pt;
    }
#menubutton p {
    margin:0;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display:inline;
    position:static;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menubuttons">
    <a id="menubutton" href=""><p>Link one</p></a>
    <a id="menubutton" href=""><p>Link two</p></a>
    <a id="menubutton" href=""><p>Link three</p></a>
    <a id="menubutton" href=""><p>Link four</p></a>
    <a id="menubutton" href=""><p>Link five</p></a>
  </div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: *Is there any good reasons for it?* I guess it depends upon what you call "good". Welcome to the joy of multi-browser support, especially when it comes to IE. Completely different development groups and code bases, each interpreting the detailed rendering rules of CSS their own way. By the way, an `id` is generally supposed to be unique on a given page. A class is used to define behavior for a collection of elements. You should define `menubutton` as a class, not an `id`.

Comment: @lurker Thank you for the good commentary, and for the information about the distinction between `id` and `class`. We'll suppose that making those kinds of distinctions is what differentiates a hobby coder from a pro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to test your code with the IE 11, Firefox, and Google Chrome browsers.

I noticed that **transform: translate** property in **#menubutton p** class causing this issue.

If you comment on it then you can see the text properly.

Modified code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML Basic 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-basic/xhtml-basic11.dtd">
<html  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8'/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/> 
<style>
.menu {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin-top:20pt
    }
.menubuttons {
    left:0%;
    height:100%;
    padding-top:20%;
    display:inline;
    position:static;
    top:20pt;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 0 0 20pt;
    }
#menubutton {
    border-radius:16px;
    background:lightblue;
    color: #000066;
    position:relative;
    height:15%;
    display:inline;
    width:60pt;
    padding:10pt 5pt 10pt 5pt;
    margin:3pt 0 3pt 3pt;
    }
#menubutton p {
    margin:0;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    /*-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
    /*transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
    display:inline;
    position:static;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menubuttons">
    <a id="menubutton" href=""><p>Link one</p></a>
    <a id="menubutton" href=""><p>Link two</p></a>
    <a id="menubutton" href=""><p>Link three</p></a>
    <a id="menubutton" href=""><p>Link four</p></a>
    <a id="menubutton" href=""><p>Link five</p></a>
  </div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Output in IE 11 browser:

[image]

Comment: That seems to be it. Thank you.

Comment: If you think that the above suggestion can help you to fix the issue then, please accept it as an answer to this question. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers